# Using two storyboards in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard

I want to use two storyboards in my application.
The scenario is if I launch my app it will use "storyBoard1" and on click of any button form viewController in storyboard1 it should launch the storyboard2.

Is it possible? I want to develop this in Swift.

Comment: @Wain how? can you send me any link of tutorial where i will get details of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it is possible.

At the moment this functionality is not available in the IDE, so you need to trick a little bit and instantiate manually the new storyboard (created as usual) and pickup the its initial view controller.

```
  let secondSTB = UIStoryboard(name: "SecondStroyboard", bundle: nil)
  let initialVCFromSecondSTB = secondSTB.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Once you have a reference to the new view controller present it as you prefer.
You can find more information [here](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/02/18/ios-storyboards-xcode5/).
In Xcode 7 will be an integrated functionality.